# Mapreduce using Scala Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce

I tried to implement a simple mapreduce job through scala. However, when I run the package using the command,

```
hadoop jar hadoop.jar mapreduce.MaxTemperature hdfs://sandbox/user/ajay/input hdfs://sandbox/user/ajay/output
```

I get the error,

```
16/09/06 16:06:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1473177830264_0002_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at mapreduce.MaxTemperatureMapper.map(MaxTemperatureMapper.scala:17)
        at mapreduce.MaxTemperatureMapper.map(MaxTemperatureMapper.scala:9)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Even though I've added the scala-library to my class path, I get the above error.

hadoop version: Hadoop 2.7.1.2.3.0.0-255
scala version: 2.11.8
java version 1.7.0_85

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a version conflict?

Comment: @Paul in my sbt build I've set the dependency as `lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "hadoop",
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.1"
    )
  )` and my hadoop version is `hadoop version
Hadoop 2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557` and java version is `java -version
java version "1.7.0_85"
`

Comment: and scala version is   scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

Comment: I don't really know much about the details here, but Predef is a class in the scala library. So either the scala library is not being found, despite you attempting to put it on the classpath, or what is found is not what's expected?

Comment: @Paul Thanks for your info, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding the scala library to the client's classpath, it has to be added to all nodes where the task gets executed. This can be achieved using the ToolRunner `hadoop jar scala-2.11/hadoop_2.11-0.1.0.jar mapreduce.WordCount -libjars /usr/lib/scala-2.11.8/lib/scala-library.jar`